# meaning of "counterpoint"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I have some problems with understanding the meaning of "counterpoint". It somewhere means "corresponding" and somewhere else "opposite", and sometimes a combination of the two meanings. How can I understand for example which meaning is intended in the following contexts?

> Context #1:
>
> In fact, Wallinger initially stumbled upon the eruv – an actual,
>   operational one – within a Jewish community in a part of North West
>   London. Subsequently, sliding down the map a little way into central
>   London this improvised demarcation served as a resonant
>   **counterpoint** to another kind of zone, an official, prohibitive one that had been decreed by the British government in 2005, namely the
>   Serious Organised Crime and Police Act.
>
> Context #2:
>
> Skulptur Projekte, taking place for the first time in 1977
>   it has been held every ten years since during the summer months,
>   rapidly gaining a reputation as one of the most significant, if
>   infrequent, international art world events. In fact, it came about to
>   some extent as a form of sculptural **counterpoint** to the
>   quinquennial Documenta held in Kassel – not a million miles away –
>   coinciding now with every second staging of this major exhibition,
>   which seeks to give curatorial impetus to the ‘global direction of
>   art’.

Answer (score 2):

A *counterpoint* is something that presents a contrast to something, namely the thing that it points counter to. This needn't be a diametric opposite, although the opposite point of view to something would be a counterpoint. It can't mean corresponding in the sense of parallel. You need to understand some details of your contexts.

Context #1: Orthodox Jews are not allowed to walk more than a certain distance on the Sabbath (less than half a mile) in public spaces, and they're not allowed to carry things when they do. Since this prohibition does not apply to private spaces, some Orthodox communities enclose their neighborhoods on the Sabbath with a symbolic fence which uses wires strung from utility poles. This creates an enlarged private space called an *eruv* within which it is permitted to walk more than the otherwise-allowed distance and to carry things while walking there. The *eruv* is a permissive area. This stands in contrast to the zones created by the Serious Organised Crime and Police Act, which allowed the police to prohibit certain activities (e.g., demonstrations) in designated areas.

Context #2: The Skulptur Projekte Münster is an exhibition of sculpture in various public areas in the city of Münster. It stands in contrast to the art exhibition Documenta in Kassel, which is not restricted to sculpture -- it presents modern art in its many forms -- but which is site-specific. The art of Documenta is shown in and on the grounds of the  Fridericianum museum.